# OpenXML tag search

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I'm writing a .NET application that should read a .docx file nearby 200 pages long (trough DocumentFormat.OpenXML 2.5) to find all the occurences of certain tags that the document should contain. 
To be clear I'm not looking for OpenXML tags but rather tags that should be set into the document by the document writer as placeholder for values I need to fill up in a second stage.
Such tags should be in the following format:

```
 <!TAG!>
```

(where TAG can be an arbitrary sequence of characters).
As I said I have to find all the occurences of such tags plus (if possibile) locating the 'page' where the tag occurence have been found.
I found something looking around in the web but more than once the base approach was to dump all the content of the file in a string and then look inside such string regardless of the .docx encoding. This either caused false positive or no match at all (while the test .docx file contains several tags), other examples were probably a little over my knowledge of OpenXML.
The regex pattern to find such tags should be something of this kind:

```
<!(.)*?!>
```

The tag can be found all over the document (inside table, text, paragraph, as also header and footer).

I'm coding in Visual Studio 2013 .NET 4.5 but I can get back if needed.
P.S. I would prefer code without use of Office Interop API since the destination platform will not run Office.

The smallest .docx example I can produce store this inside document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
<w:body>
<w:p w:rsidR="00CA7780" w:rsidRDefault="00815E5D">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>TRY</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00815E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00815E5D">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>&lt;!TAG1</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>!&gt;</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00815E5D" w:rsidRPr="00815E5D" w:rsidRDefault="00815E5D">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>TRY2</w:t>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="00815E5D" w:rsidRPr="00815E5D">
  <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/>
  <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1134" w:left="1134" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/>
  <w:cols w:space="708"/>
  <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
</w:sectPr>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

Best Regards,
 Mike

Comment: so you actually have the xml-document extracted allready?

Comment: If so can you show us a small sample of it?

Comment: @Florian What do you mean with 'extracted'? Anyway I can attach the file here if I find the way....

Comment: the docx file is a .zip file under the hood... containing a folderstructure with some xml documents inside... you can try by renaming a .docx to .zip (would have to disable omit known file extensions in the explorer to do so)

Comment: Yep I know that but I think that DocumentFormat.OpenXML does extract the file by itself? I'm wrong?

Comment: if you got that down you can load the respecive xml documents using the System.Linq.Xml Namespace and you are there ... if i could see a sample of what you trying to find i can give you an anwer as how to select/alter the elements in the xml

Comment: Anyway if you need to see how 'document.xml' looks like I can provide it ... but since it's quite long is probably better to add just a segment. What you need?

Comment: Just a segment will do... to see what you are looking for

Comment: So you suggest a different approach than OpenXML SDK. Ok... that's a sample of the document.xml but it's just a test case not the real one:

Comment: I never used this library... i just got it by nuget... not sure

Comment: Ok I managed to embed the xml code in the answer. As you can see '<!TAG1!>' entry is split between different lines and w:t items... it's quite difficult to find it inside the xml source code.

Comment: And you want to get the  <w:t>&lt;!TAG1</w:t> ? right?

Comment: In this format you will have trouble without any further preprocessing.
See the &lt;!TAG1 of yours? It is split up into two nodes with the closing &gt; being in another node because of Word's grammar checker.
You might want to try opening the file in Word first, Select All and set to "Do not Check grammar and spelling" and set the language of the entire document to one language first.

Word is a b-h when it comes to ripping up content in the document's code like this.

Comment: @LocEngineer I cannot reprocess the file trough Word the file is produced elsewere and the platform running my application it's not running Office. One possibile solution I found is to descend into the .docx structure merging paragraphs, text, table contents saving just text entries.. on the resulting string I can then apply a regex search with some chance to find what I'm looking for,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem with trying to find tags is that words are not always in the underlying XML in the format that they appear to be in Word. For example, in your sample XML the `<!TAG1!>` tag is split across multiple runs like this:

```
<w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>&lt;!TAG1</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:lang w:val="en-GB"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>!&gt;</w:t>
</w:r>
```

As pointed out in the comments this is sometimes caused by the spelling and grammar checker but that's not all that can cause it. Having different styles on parts of the tag could also cause it for example.

One way of handling this is to find the `InnerText` of a `Paragraph` and compare that against your `Regex`. The `InnerText` property will return the plain text of the paragraph without any formatting or other XML within the underlying document getting in the way.

Once you have your tags, replacing the text is the next problem. Due to the above reasons you can't just replace the `InnerText` with some new text as it wouldn't be clear as to which parts of the text would belong in which `Run`. The easiest way round this is to remove any existing `Run`'s and add a new `Run` with a `Text` property containing the new text.

The following code shows finding the tags and replacing them immediately rather than using two passes as you suggest in your question. This was just to make the example simpler to be honest. It should show everything you need.

```
private static void ReplaceTags(string filename)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex("<!(.)*?!>", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filename, true))
    {
        //grab the header parts and replace tags there
        foreach (HeaderPart headerPart in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.HeaderParts)
        {
            ReplaceParagraphParts(headerPart.Header, regex);
        }
        //now do the document
        ReplaceParagraphParts(wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document, regex);
        //now replace the footer parts
        foreach (FooterPart footerPart in wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.FooterParts)
        {
            ReplaceParagraphParts(footerPart.Footer, regex);
        }
    }
}

private static void ReplaceParagraphParts(OpenXmlElement element, Regex regex)
{
    foreach (var paragraph in element.Descendants<Paragraph>())
    {
        Match match = regex.Match(paragraph.InnerText);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            //create a new run and set its value to the correct text
            //this must be done before the child runs are removed otherwise
            //paragraph.InnerText will be empty
            Run newRun = new Run();
            newRun.AppendChild(new Text(paragraph.InnerText.Replace(match.Value, "some new value")));
            //remove any child runs
            paragraph.RemoveAllChildren<Run>();
            //add the newly created run
            paragraph.AppendChild(newRun);
        }
    }
}
```

One downside with the above approach is that any styles you may have had will be lost. These could be copied from the existing `Run`'s but if there are multiple `Run`'s with differing properties you'll need to work out which ones you need to copy where. There's nothing to stop you creating multiple `Run`'s in the above code each with different properties if that's what is required. Other elements would also be lost (e.g. any symbols) so those would need to be accounted for too.

Comment: That's really what I was lookin' for ... more then this you already forecast the real problem that should be the replacement. In my opinion the `<!tag!>` entry should not contain change of styles then I can assume that `Runs` will not change across it...

Comment: @weirdgyn, as noted by @petelids, the problem with the above approach is that for each paragraph having at least one run with your tag, _all_ runs in those paragraphs will lose their styling. Further, in each of those paragraphs, you will lose all symbols and all fields (e.g., REF). Bookmarks (`w:bookmarkStart` and `w:bookmarkEnd` elements) and inline structured document tags (`w:sdt` elements) will create further issues.

Comment: Thanks. I was struggling to get this code to work, apparently I had the wrong namespace. For anyone in the future you need the `using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;` namespace not the `Drawing` one. Both have the same classes but ofcourse a different implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the SDK is better but this works and produces a dictionary that contain the name of the tag and an element you could set the new value to:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication8
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<string, XElement> lookupTable = new Dictionary<string, XElement>();
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\<\!(?<TagName>.*)\!\>");

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("document.xml");
            XNamespace ns = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "t").Where(x=> x.Value.StartsWith("<!")).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in elements)
            {
                #region remove the grammar tag
                //before
                XElement grammar = item.Parent.PreviousNode as XElement;
                grammar.Remove();
                //after
                grammar = item.Parent.NextNode as XElement;
                grammar.Remove();
                #endregion
                #region merge the two nodes and insert the name and the XElement to the dictionary
                XElement next = (item.Parent.NextNode as XElement).Element(ns + "t");
                string totalTagName = string.Format("{0}{1}", item.Value, next.Value);
                item.Parent.NextNode.Remove();
                item.Value = totalTagName;
                lookupTable.Add(reg.Match(totalTagName).Groups["TagName"].Value, item);
                #endregion
            }
            foreach (var item in lookupTable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The document contains a tag {0}" , item.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value.ToString());
            }


        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

A more complete example of the possible structure you can make:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO.Compression; //you will have to add a reference to System.IO.Compression.FileSystem(.dll)
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication28
{
    public class MyWordDocument
    {
        #region fields

        private string fileName;
        private XDocument document;
        //todo: create fields for all document xml files that can contain the placeholders

        private Dictionary<string, List<XElement>> lookUpTable;

        #endregion

        #region properties

        public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get { return lookUpTable.Keys; } }

        #endregion

        #region construction

        public MyWordDocument(string fileName)
        {
            this.fileName = fileName;
            ExtractDocument();
            CreateLookUp();
        }

        #endregion
        #region methods

        public void ReplaceTagWithValue(string tagName, string value)
        {
            foreach (var item in lookUpTable[tagName])
            {
                item.Value = item.Value.Replace(string.Format(@"<!{0}!>", tagName),value);
            }
        }

        public void Save(string fileName)
        {
            document.Save(@"temp\word\document.xml");
            //todo: save other parts of document here i.e. footer header or other stuff

            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory("temp", fileName);
        }

        private void CreateLookUp()
        {
            //todo: make this work for all cases and for all files that can contain the placeholders
            //tip: open the raw document in word and replace the tags,
            //     save the file to different location and extract the xmlfiles of both versions and compare to see what you have to do
            lookUpTable = new Dictionary<string, List<XElement>>();
            Regex reg = new Regex(@"\<\!(?<TagName>.*)\!\>");
            document = XDocument.Load(@"temp\word\document.xml");
            XNamespace ns = document.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");
            IEnumerable<XElement> elements = document.Root.Descendants(ns + "t").Where(NodeGotSplitUpIn2PartsDueToGrammarCheck).ToArray();
            foreach (var item in elements)
            {
                XElement grammar = item.Parent.PreviousNode as XElement;
                grammar.Remove();
                grammar = item.Parent.NextNode as XElement;
                grammar.Remove();
                XElement next = (item.Parent.NextNode as XElement).Element(ns + "t");
                string totalTagName = string.Format("{0}{1}", item.Value, next.Value);
                item.Parent.NextNode.Remove();
                item.Value = totalTagName;
                string tagName = reg.Match(totalTagName).Groups["TagName"].Value;
                if (lookUpTable.ContainsKey(tagName))
                {
                    lookUpTable[tagName].Add(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    lookUpTable.Add(tagName, new List<XElement> { item });
                }
            }
        }

        private bool NodeGotSplitUpIn2PartsDueToGrammarCheck(XElement node)
        {
            XNamespace ns = node.Document.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("w");
            return node.Value.StartsWith("<!") && ((XElement)node.Parent.PreviousNode).Name == ns + "proofErr";
        }


        private void ExtractDocument()
        {
            if (!Directory.Exists("temp"))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");
            }
            else
            {
                Directory.Delete("temp",true);
                Directory.CreateDirectory("temp");
            }
            ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(fileName, "temp");
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyWordDocument doc = new MyWordDocument("somedoc.docx"); //todo: fix path

        foreach (string name in doc.Tags) //name would be the extracted name from the placeholder
        {
            doc.ReplaceTagWithValue(name, "Example");
        }

        doc.Save("output.docx"); //todo: fix path
    }
}
```

Comment: pretty sure this would need tweaking though for other cases(tables etc) but the concept is the same I think

Comment: TagName is supposedly to be know beforehand ?

Comment: No you drag it out using the pattern

Comment: @weirdgyn added a template for the solution

Comment: @weirdgyn another thing you could do is make a interface ISearchAndFixPlaceholders{ IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,XElement>>FindAndFix(XDocument doc)} and split the task into multiple classes

Answer (score 1):

I have the same need as you do with the exception that I want to use `${...}` entries instead of `<!...!>`. You could customize the code below to use your tags but it would require more states.

The following code works for xml as well as openxml nodes. I tested the code using xml, because when it comes to word documents it is hard to control how word arranges the paragraphs, runs & text elements. I guess it is not impossible, but this way I have more control:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  //FillInValues(FileName("test01.docx"), FileName("test01_out.docx"));

  string[,] tests =
  {
    { "<r><t>${abc</t><t>}$</t><t>{tha}</t></r>", "<r><t>ABC</t><t>THA</t><t></t></r>"},
    { "<r><t>$</t><t>{</t><t>abc</t><t>}</t></r>", "<r><t>ABC</t><t></t></r>"},
    {"<r><t>${abc}</t></r>", "<r><t>ABC</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${abc}</t></r>", "<r><t>xABC</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${abc}y</t></r>", "<r><t>xABCy</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${abc}${tha}z</t></r>", "<r><t>xABCTHAz</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${abc}u${tha}z</t></r>", "<r><t>xABCuTHAz</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${ab</t><t>c}u</t></r>", "<r><t>xABC</t><t>u</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${ab</t><t>yupeekaiiei</t><t>c}u</t></r>", "<r><t>xABYUPEEKAIIEIC</t><t>u</t></r>" },
    {"<r><t>x${ab</t><t>yupeekaiiei</t><t>}</t></r>", "<r><t>xABYUPEEKAIIEI</t><t></t></r>" },

  };


  for (int i = 0; i < tests.GetLength(0); i++)
  {
    string value = tests[i, 0];
    string expectedValue = tests[i, 1];
    string actualValue = Test(value);
    Console.WriteLine($"{value} => {actualValue} == {expectedValue} = {actualValue == expectedValue}");

  }

  Console.WriteLine("Done!");
  Console.ReadLine();
}


public interface ITextReplacer
{
  string ReplaceValue(string value);
}

public class DefaultTextReplacer : ITextReplacer
{
  public string ReplaceValue(string value) { return $"{value.ToUpper()}"; }
}

public interface ITextElement
{
  string Value { get; set; }
  void RemoveFromParent();
}


public class XElementWrapper : ITextElement
{
  private XElement _element;

  public XElementWrapper(XElement element) { _element = element; }

  string ITextElement.Value
  {
    get { return _element.Value; }
    set { _element.Value = value; }
  }

  public XElement Element
  {
    get { return _element; }
    set { _element = value; }
  }

  public void RemoveFromParent()
  {
    _element.Remove();
  }


}

public class OpenXmlTextWrapper : ITextElement
{
  private Text _text;
  public OpenXmlTextWrapper(Text text) { _text = text; }

  public string Value
  {
    get { return _text.Text; }
    set { _text.Text = value; }
  }

  public Text Text
  {
    get { return _text; }
    set { _text = value; }
  }

  public void RemoveFromParent() { _text.Remove(); }
}


private static void FillInValues(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
{
  File.Copy(sourceFileName, destFileName, true);

  using (WordprocessingDocument doc =
    WordprocessingDocument.Open(destFileName, true))
  {
    var body = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    var paras = body.Descendants<Paragraph>();

    SimpleStateMachine stateMachine = new SimpleStateMachine();

    //stateMachine.TextReplacer = <your implementation object >
    ProcessParagraphs(paras, stateMachine);
  }
}

private static void ProcessParagraphs(IEnumerable<Paragraph> paras, SimpleStateMachine stateMachine)
{
  foreach (var para in paras)
  {
    foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
    {
      //Console.WriteLine("New run:");

      var texts = run.Elements<Text>().ToArray();

      for (int k = 0; k < texts.Length; k++)
      {
        OpenXmlTextWrapper wrapper = new OpenXmlTextWrapper(texts[k]);
        stateMachine.HandleText(wrapper);
      }
    }
  }
}

public class SimpleStateMachine
{
  // 0 - outside - initial state
  // 1 - $ matched
  // 2 - ${ matched
  // 3 - } - final state

  // 0 -> 1 $
  // 0 -> 0 anything other than $
  // 1 -> 2 {
  // 1 -> 0 anything other than {
  // 2 -> 3 }
  // 2 -> 2 anything other than }
  // 3 -> 0

  public ITextReplacer TextReplacer { get; set; } = new DefaultTextReplacer();
  public int State { get; set; } = 0;
  public List<ITextElement> TextsList { get; } = new List<ITextElement>();
  public StringBuilder Buffer { get; } = new StringBuilder();


  /// <summary>
  /// The index inside the Text element where the $ is found
  /// </summary>
  public int Position { get; set; }

  public void Reset()
  {
    State = 0;
    TextsList.Clear();
    Buffer.Clear();
  }

  public void Add(ITextElement text)
  {
    if (TextsList.Count == 0 || TextsList.Last() != text)
    {
      TextsList.Add(text);
    }
  }

  public void HandleText(ITextElement text)
  {
    // Scan the characters

    for (int i = 0; i < text.Value.Length; i++)
    {
      char c = text.Value[i];

      switch (State)
      {
        case 0:
          if (c == '$')
          {
            State = 1;
            Position = i;
            Add(text);
          }
          break;
        case 1:
          if (c == '{')
          {
            State = 2;
            Add(text);
          }
          else
          {
            Reset();
          }
          break;
        case 2:
          if (c == '}')
          {
            Add(text);

            Console.WriteLine("Found: " + Buffer);
            // We are on the final State
            // I will use the first text in the stack and discard the others


            // Here I am going to distinguish between whether I have only one item or more
            if (TextsList.Count == 1)
            {
              // Happy path - we have only one item - set the replacement value and then continue scanning
              string prefix = TextsList[0].Value.Substring(0, Position) + TextReplacer.ReplaceValue(Buffer.ToString());
              // Set the current index to point to the end of the prefix.The program will continue to with the next items
              TextsList[0].Value = prefix + TextsList[0].Value.Substring(i + 1);
              i = prefix.Length - 1;
              Reset();
            }
            else
            {
              // We have more than one item - discard the inbetweeners

              for (int j = 1; j < TextsList.Count - 1; j++)
              {
                TextsList[j].RemoveFromParent();
              }

              // I will set the value under the first Text item where the $ was found
              TextsList[0].Value = TextsList[0].Value.Substring(0, Position) + TextReplacer.ReplaceValue(Buffer.ToString());
              // Set the text for the current item to the remaining chars
              text.Value = text.Value.Substring(i + 1);
              i = -1;
              Reset();
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Buffer.Append(c);
            Add(text);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  }
}

public static string Test(string xml)
{
  XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
  SimpleStateMachine stateMachine = new SimpleStateMachine();


  foreach (XElement element in root.Descendants()
    .Where(desc => !desc.Elements().Any()))
  {
    XElementWrapper wrapper = new XElementWrapper(element);
    stateMachine.HandleText(wrapper);
  }

  return root.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting);
}
```

I know my answer is late but it might be of use to others. Also make sure you test it. I am going to do more testing tomorrow with real documents. If I find any bugs I will fix the code here, but so far so good.

Update: the code doesn't work when the `${...}` placeholders are placed in a table. This is a problem with the code that scans the document (the FillInValues function).

Update: I changed the code to scan all paragraphs.

Comment: It looks as a reasonable solution but I haven't tested it.

Comment: I just modified the source code to use the same method for xml and openxml. If you decide to use it and find any issues, let me know.

Comment: Hallo up to now I switched for a different approach and I had to use a commercial API instead writing my own.

Comment: @weirdgyn: Aspose.Words does use `<<...>>` tags that can be replaced with object values. Do you use Aspose? Just curious. For me buying a commercial at this time is out of the question. I would have gone with it.