# Modifed word document not saving in memorystream

Tags: c#, .net-core, openxml, openxml-sdk, openxml-powertools

I am getting a word document from SharePoint using Microsoft graph API as a stream and changing some content in that file and downloading the saved content as a file but when I open the file, the modified content is not available. The downloaded file still shows the original content.

```
       using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
         {
            templateStream.Position = 0;
            // Copying the stream that I've got into memory stream
            await templateStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
            memoryStream.Position = 0;

            using (var wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStream, true))
            {
                RevisionAccepter.AcceptRevisions(wordDocument);
                var document = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.GetXDocument();
                var content = document.Descendants(W.p).ToList();
                //based on the dictionary I've I am replacing the contents of the file
                foreach (var field in dataDictionary)
                {
                    var regex = new Regex(field.Key, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    OpenXmlRegex.Replace(content, regex, field.Value.ToString(), null);
                }
                //not showing the modified content
                wordDocument.Save();
                //this is also not updating the memorystream variable with the modified content
                wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                await memoryStream.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            var result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            memoryStream.Flush();
            return result;
        }
```

once I got the byte array from the above code I am downloading the file using this line from my controller

```
  return File(returnResponse, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, $"Test- 
               {System.DateTime.Now}.docx");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you try hardcoding a change in the `foreach` area? Is it possible that no content is being updated?

Comment: Please add the code that is getting the templateStream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As outlined in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931501/c-sharp-openxml-search-and-replace-text-not-saving) you need to call [PutXDocument()](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/-/OpenXmlPart/PutXDocument/php-openxmlpart-putxdocument-method-examples.html) method on the `MainDocumentPart` for your changes to be successfully reflected, because currently, you are making changes but not commiting them to the required document.