# why my c# function works only in that way?

Tags: c#, string, function, openxml

i'm trying to replace text on a docx file with Open XML SDK, it works fine , so it replace it since i write "hi" and word "hello" passing them directly to regexText.Replace like this:

> working

```
public static void SearchAndReplace(string document, string find, string replaced)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document, true))
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            {
                docText = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Regex regexText = new Regex("hi");
            docText = regexText.Replace("hello");

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
            {
                sw.Write(docText);
            }
        }
    }
```

but when i try to call functions using variables passed the code doesn't replace the word "hi" with "hello", but why ? what is changing the code to make it fail?
(i mean the code is compiling and it doesn't throw any exception, but it doesn't replace)

> not working

```
SearchAndReplace("template.docx", "hi", "hello");
```

and change this, nothing else:

```
Regex regexText = new Regex(find);
docText = regexText.Replace(docText, replace);
```

Comment: Is that actually the parameters you pass? `"hi"` and `"hello"`? And are you working with the same starting document (exactly copies) in *both* cases?

Comment: Just to note: your showing two different overloads for `.Replace`, your first sample only takes one parameter. Also your second snippet uses the name `replace` instead of `replaced` as is in the first sample.

Comment: oh thank i didn't see, but i didn't make that mistake in my real code :c btw now it cames out error opening the file, i'm getting so mad.

Comment: now i  can't even open any document with word in my pc, it crash everytime , i think i'm done for today

Comment: Perhaps you should start more simply and write a `FindAndReplace` method. Then you can test that with regular strings without worrying about opening a word document. Once that's working, you can call it from a `FindAndReplaceInDocument` method, which opens the doc, extracts the text, calls your other method to do the replace, and updated the document.

Comment: For the record, you don't need `Regex` for this, either - the `string` class has a built-in `Replace` method, which you could use like: `docText = docText.Replace(find, replace);`

Comment: You might run into other problems when trying to replace text this way - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697701/openxml-tag-search/28719853#28719853) for details.