# OpenXML Find Replace Text

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, docx

**Environment**

Visual Studio 2017 C# (Word .docx file)

**Problem**

The find/replace only replaces "{Today}" - it fails to replace the "{ConsultantName}" field. I've checked the document and tried using different approaches (see commented-out code) but no joy.

The Word document has just a few paragraphs of text - there are no tables or text boxes in the document. What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

When I inspect **doc_text** string, I can see "{Today}" but "{ConsultantName}" is split into multiple runs. The opening and closing braces are not together with the word - there are XML tags between them:

```
{</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:r w:rsidR="00544806"><w:t>ConsultantName</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:r w:rsidR="00544806"><w:t>}
```

**Code**

```
    string doc_text = string.Empty;
    List<string> s_find = new List<string>();
    List<string> s_replace = new List<string>();
    // Regex regexText = null;

    s_find.Add("{Today}");
    s_replace.Add("24 Sep 2018");
    s_find.Add("{ConsultantName}");
    s_replace.Add("John Doe");

    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
    {
        // read document
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
        {
            doc_text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // find replace
        for (byte b = 0; b < s_find.Count; b++)
        {
            doc_text = new Regex(s_find[b], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Replace(doc_text, s_replace[b]);
            // regexText = new Regex(s_find[b]);
            // doc_text = doc_text.Replace(s_find[b], s_replace[b]);
            // doc_text = regexText.Replace(doc_text, s_replace[b]);
        }

        // update document
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create)))
        {
            sw.Write(doc_text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This might be useful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697701/openxml-tag-search/28719853#28719853

Answer (score 2):

Note: I want to avoid using Word Interop. I don't want to create an instance of Word and use Word's object model to do the Find/Replace.

There is no way to avoid Word splitting text into multiple runs. It happens even if you type text directly into the document, make no changes and apply no formatting.

However, I found a way around the problem by adding custom fields to the document as follows:

- Open Word document. Go to **File->Info**
- Click the **Properties** heading and select **Advanced Properties**.
- Select the **Custom** tab.
- Add the field names you want to use and Save.
- In the document click **Insert** on the main menu.
- Click **Explore Quick Parts** icon and select **Field...**
- Drop-down **Categories** and select **Document Information**.
- Under Field names: select **DocProperty**.
- Select your custom field name in the "Property" list and click ok.

This inserts the field into your document and even if you apply formatting, the field name will be whole and not be broken into multiple runs.

**Update**

To save users the laborious task of manually adding a lot of custom properties to a document, I wrote a method to do this using OpenXML.

Add the following usings:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.VariantTypes;
```

Code to add custom (text) properties to the document:

```
static public bool RunWordDocumentAddProperties(string filePath, List<string> strName, List<string> strVal)
{
    bool is_ok = true;
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filePath) == false)
            return false;                

        using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
        {
            var customProps = wordDoc.CustomFilePropertiesPart;
            if (customProps == null)
            {
                // no custom properties? Add the part, and the collection of properties
                customProps = wordDoc.AddCustomFilePropertiesPart();
                customProps.Properties = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.CustomProperties.Properties();
            }
            for (byte b = 0; b < strName.Count; b++)
            {
                var props = customProps.Properties;                        
                if (props != null)
                {
                    var newProp = new CustomDocumentProperty();
                    newProp.VTLPWSTR = new VTLPWSTR(strVal[b].ToString());
                    newProp.FormatId = "{D5CDD505-2E9C-101B-9397-08002B2CF9AE}";
                    newProp.Name = strName[b];

                    // append the new property, and fix up all the property ID values
                    // property ID values must start at 2
                    props.AppendChild(newProp);
                    int pid = 2;
                    foreach (CustomDocumentProperty item in props)
                    {
                        item.PropertyId = pid++;
                    }
                    props.Save();
                }
            }                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        is_ok = false;
        ProcessError(ex);
    }
    return is_ok;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do this:

*.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.12.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

add these packages:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
```

and put this code in your system

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument =
            WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath, true))
        {
            var body = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;

            var paras = body.Elements<Paragraph>();

            foreach (var para in paras)
            {
                foreach (var run in para.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    foreach (var text in run.Elements<Text>())
                    {
                        if (text.Text.Contains("#_KEY_1_#"))
                        {
                            text.Text = text.Text.Replace("#_KEY_1_#", "replaced-text");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

done

Comment: So this doesn't work for my word document. The `paras` is empty.

Comment: try with the keys #KEY# - only words and #

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a solution for replacing text in Word, Excel, and PowerPoint documents. It utilizes a simple dictionary-based approach, providing an easy way to define your replacements.

**Usage:**

```
Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new()
{
    { "##keyword##", sampleText },
};

IFileHandler fileHandler = FileHandlerFactory.Create(yourFileExtension); //docx, xlsx, pptx

byte[] updatedFile = fileHandler.UpdateFile(originalFile, replacements); //byte[]
```

**Best Practice**: I recommend using ## as a prefix and postfix for your keywords and inserting them in lowercase. This ensures reliable keyword recognition and replacement.

**Code:**

```
    public interface IFileHandler
{
    byte[] UpdateFile(byte[] file, Dictionary<string, string> replacements);
}

public static class FileHandlerFactory
{
    public static IFileHandler Create(string fileExtension)
    {
        return fileExtension switch
        {
            "docx" => new WordDocumentHandler(),
            "xlsx" => new ExcelHandler(),
            "pptx" => new PowerPointHandler(),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException("File type not supported"),
        };
    }
}

public class WordDocumentHandler : IFileHandler
{
    public byte[] UpdateFile(byte[] file, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
    {
        string temporaryFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".docx");
        File.WriteAllBytes(temporaryFilePath, file);

        using (WordprocessingDocument document = WordprocessingDocument.Open(temporaryFilePath, isEditable: true))
        {
            MainDocumentPart? documentPart = document.MainDocumentPart;

            if (documentPart != null)
            {
                var header = documentPart.HeaderParts.SelectMany(header => header.RootElement!.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>());
                var body = documentPart.Document.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>();
                var footer = documentPart.FooterParts.SelectMany(header => header.RootElement!.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Text>());

                var allText = header.Concat(body).Concat(footer);

                foreach (var textElement in allText)
                {
                    string textContent = textElement.Text;
                    foreach (var replacement in replacements.Where(replacement => textContent.Contains(replacement.Key)))
                    {
                        textElement.Text = textElement.Text.Replace(textContent, replacement.Value);
                    }
                }

                document.Save();
            }
        }

        return File.ReadAllBytes(temporaryFilePath);
    }
}

public class ExcelHandler : IFileHandler
{
    public byte[] UpdateFile(byte[] file, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
    {
        string temporaryFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xlsx");
        File.WriteAllBytes(temporaryFilePath, file);

        using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(temporaryFilePath, isEditable: true))
        {
            WorkbookPart? workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;

            if (workbookPart != null)
            {
                workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.ForceFullCalculation = true;
                workbookPart.Workbook.CalculationProperties.FullCalculationOnLoad = true;

                SharedStringTablePart? sharedStringTablePart = workbookPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>().FirstOrDefault();

                if (sharedStringTablePart != null)
                {
                    foreach (WorksheetPart worksheetPart in workbookPart.WorksheetParts)
                    {
                        GetCells(worksheetPart).ForEach(cell => ProcessCell(replacements, cell, sharedStringTablePart));
                    }
                }

                document.Save();
            }
        }

        return File.ReadAllBytes(temporaryFilePath);
    }

    private static List<Cell> GetCells(WorksheetPart worksheetPart)
    {
        return worksheetPart.Worksheet.Elements<SheetData>().SelectMany(i => i.Elements<Row>())
            .SelectMany(i => i.Elements<Cell>()).ToList();
    }

    private static void ProcessCell(Dictionary<string, string> replacements, Cell cell, SharedStringTablePart sharedStringTablePart)
    {
        bool isValidCell = cell.DataType != null && cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString && cell.CellValue != null;

        if (isValidCell)
        {
            int sharedStringIndex = int.Parse(cell.CellValue.InnerText);
            SharedStringItem sharedStringItem = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable.Elements<SharedStringItem>().ElementAt(sharedStringIndex);

            string? text = sharedStringItem.Text?.Text;
            foreach (var replacement in replacements.Where(replacement => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && text.Contains(replacement.Key)))
            {
                cell.CellValue = new CellValue(replacement.Value);
                cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(CellValues.String);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class PowerPointHandler : IFileHandler
{
    public byte[] UpdateFile(byte[] file, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
    {
        string temporaryFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".pptx");
        File.WriteAllBytes(temporaryFilePath, file);

        using (PresentationDocument document = PresentationDocument.Open(temporaryFilePath, isEditable: true))
        {
            PresentationPart? presentationPart = document.PresentationPart;

            if (presentationPart != null)
            {
                foreach (SlideMasterPart slideMasterPart in presentationPart.SlideMasterParts)
                {
                    ReplaceText(slideMasterPart.SlideMaster.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>(), replacements);
                }

                foreach (SlidePart slidePart in presentationPart.SlideParts)
                {
                    ReplaceText(slidePart.Slide.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text>(), replacements);
                }
            }

            document.Save();
        }

        return File.ReadAllBytes(temporaryFilePath);
    }

    private static void ReplaceText(IEnumerable<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Text> texts, Dictionary<string, string> replacements)
    {
        foreach (var text in texts)
        {
            foreach (var replacement in replacements.Where(replacement => text.Text.Contains(replacement.Key)))
            {
                text.Text = text.Text.Replace(replacement.Key, replacement.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Key Points:**

- Handles Headers/Footers (Word): Ensures text replacement throughout the entire document.
- Calculated Cells (Excel): Accurately updates text within calculated cells.
- Master Slides (PowerPoint): Replaces text in master slides for consistency.