# "ProofError" elements causing issues in OpenXML

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to read through a word document using Open XML.
I am looking for key tags within the document in order to identify the values i need to pick up from the document.

I am looping through each paragraph, and then each run within the document to be able to find these.
However it appears that the spelling & grammar check is causing problems, splitting up the "runs" within the documents with any errors it identifies with "ProofError" elements, which is making it difficult to parse the document correctly.

I have tried to remove all ProofError elements and save the document, however they appear to come back.
If i run the spelling and grammar check within MS Word manually there is no issue, though this isn't practical.

Does anyone know a way I can get around this?

Sample text from doc:

> Communication System: UID 0, CW (0); Frequency: 900 MHz;Duty Cycle: 1:1
>   Medium: 900MHz HSL Medium parameters used: f = 900 MHz; σ = 0.979 S/m; εr = 40.68; ρ = 1000 kg/m3

Code used to explore the document

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, false))
{
    // start looking through the file here
    // correct proof errors here
    Body body = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
    foreach (Paragraph p in body.OfType<Paragraph>())
    {
        p.GetType();
        List<ProofError> errList = new List<ProofError>();
        foreach (ProofError err in p.OfType<ProofError>())
        {
            errList.Add(err);
        }
        foreach (ProofError err in errList)
        {
            err.Remove();
        } 
    }
    wordDocument.Save();
}
```

The code above will remove any of the ProofError elements from the list, I hope that doing this and saving it would merge any similar runs together, however the proof errors come back when saving.

Screenshot below should show you the children of a paragraph.
Link to an example Document which throws up errors - these are due to the language being incorrect, but i have no control over the format coming in to me, and there will be other errors thrown up unrelated to language.

[image: Paragraph Children]

[Sample File](http://rhythmmax.co.uk/parse.docx)

Comment: Can you share the document (or a sample doc) and also the code you're running?

Comment: @PaulKaram - Im not able to share the document, but ill work on coming up with a sample document quickly, and ill post the code im using the expore the xml. Thanks

Comment: @PaulKaram - I have added a sample document, the code I am using and a screenshot of the children within a paragraph

Comment: Have a look at my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697701/openxml-tag-search/28719853#28719853. That might be of use.

Comment: @petelids Thanks for linking me to this. This is the method I am using right now, looking through paragraphs instead. As i do not need to edit the documents in anyway, this shouldn't be too much of an issue, it just makes the parsing a little less flexible.

Thanks