# How to do string replacements in Office OpenXML when text spans multiple OpenXML elements?

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

I've noticed while parsing .docx using Office Open XML that sentences will be broken up by a ton of run, formatting, proofing and other elements. E.g. "Hello world" will look like:

```
Hello</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:rFonts w:ascii=\"Arial\" w:hAnsi=\"Arial\" w:cs=\"Arial\"/><w:noProof/><w:sz w:val=\"20\"/></w:rPr> World"
```

This makes it very tough to do string replacements.

Is there an easy way or best practice to replace "Hello world" in this situation?

Comment: Probably not a simple way if you want to retain formatting...

Comment: That's what I figured. I'm basically iterating over all the text and ignoring everything between < and > until I get to the end of my string, doing replacements along the way. 

The strange thing is, there is no formatting in these situations, just a bunch of self closing elements that have no impact on the actual text

Comment: Are you using the OpenXml SDK?  I thought that there was a way to look for text that ignored runs, and the other goop (but, it's been a while).  Like, for example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-search-and-replace-text-in-a-document-part

Comment: I am using the SDK and actually am using that exact code sample but that code returns all the text plus the OpenXML elements.

Comment: This answer might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697701/openxml-tag-search/28719853#28719853